# Functions with recurring loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a function that has a default input of nothing and will continue to recur(if user inputs nothing  until user inputs a character. the issue is that that i am stuck trying to get the input question to recur from within the loop.

```html
#### Default
usr_int =("")

def str_analysis():
    usr_int = (input("enter word or integer: "))
    while (usr_int == ("")):
        if usr_int.isdigit():
            if (usr_int <= 99):
                return (usr_int, "is a smaller number than expected")
            elif (usr_int >= 100):
                return (usr_int, "is a pretty big number")
        elif usr_int.isalpha():
            if usr_int.isdigit():
                return (usr_int, "has multiple character types")
            else:
                return (usr_int, "is all alphabetical characters!")
        else:
            usr_int = (input("enter word or integer: "))
    
out_2 = str_analysis()
print(out_2)
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

A couple months back, I wanted to do somewhat the same thing that you what to do now.

I found a function for it

```
# Required library import
import msvcrt as m
while True :
    # The required function to use KeyButtonHIT
    if m.kbhit() :
        ch = m.getch().decode()
    else :
        ch = ''
    # Rest of the code in a loop
```

You can similarly use the kbhit function for recursion.

Comment: sadly i can't use the kbhit function as it has not been part of the course.

Answer (score 0):

```html
#### Default
usr_int =("")

def str_analysis():
    usr_int = (input("enter word or integer: "))
    while True:
     if usr_int.isdigit():
            if (int(usr_int) <= 99):
                return (usr_int, "is a smaller number than expected")
            elif (int(usr_int) >= 100):
                return (usr_int, "is a pretty big number")
     elif usr_int.isalpha():
            if usr_int.isdigit():
                return (usr_int, "has multiple character types")
            else:
                return (usr_int, "is all alphabetical characters!")
     else:
            usr_int = (input("enter word or integer: "))
    
out_2 = str_analysis()
print(out_2)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about how this code works or could solve the OP problem.